# Basic User Management, For Custom Site

Tags: php, asp.net, wordpress, joomla

I have been looking at either coding from scratch a basic login page + session management user validation for a new website I intend to build.

I am wary that this may not be the safest thing for me to do on my own, so I am contemplating using joomla or wordpress for basic user authentication and then having the rest of the site pretty much customised. Is this a good idea, or am I going against how they were designed and is there a better framework I could be using for this simple task? I am not too concerned with language but asp.net or php are definitely preferred.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For ASP .NET you should use [ASP .Net Membership](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh26yfzy.aspx)
a series of tutorial regarding to implement asp .net membership can be [find here](https://web.archive.org/web/20211020202857/http://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/120705-1.aspx)

Comment: in the end i used asp.net membership it has been a good choice so far

Answer (score 0):

I use Joomla allot, but if everything else is custom, it would probably hold you back rather than help.

I would take a look at http://codeigniter.com and use one of the authentication plugins.

Answer (score 0):

stackoverflow uses OpenIDs, which I think is pretty handy. This will manage your authentication, but you'll still need to "register" the users (ie their user name and profile and OpenID token) on your server. But I think authentication is the biggest headache, so with that out of the way, the rest is pretty standard.

Answer (score 0):

I like WordPress a lot and think it's a good tool for certain things, but I don't think I'd use its codebase as a starting point for a new app. Try a more generic web-app framework in your preferred language... Yii or CakePHP if you want PHP... you'll find user/session/authentication plugins to get you started, and then you can go from there, with a relatively blank slate and the handy don't-reinvent-the-wheel tools a framework provides.